# Is there any advantage using this kind of ROM-based randomized hashing in digital signatures?

Tags: hash, padding

The said randomized hasing is actually a sort of padding, and it goes like this:

```
Parameters: 
1. hash function H()
2. length N in bytes of the output of the hash function.
Input: 
1. M the message to hash.
Generate:
1. Generate r := N/2 random bytes.
2. Compute lo := H(r|M)
3. Compute hi := r xor lo
4. _Return (hi|lo)
Verify:
1. Compute r := hi xor lo
2. Compute v := H(r|M)
3. _Return v == lo
```

Is there any advantage to it other than slightly better verification of the correctness of the padding?

Comment: This has some similarities with the [padding in RSA-PSS](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=35), when the the RSA modulus is just above twice as wide as the hash. Simplified to the max, which is nice.

Comment: I admit it as my inspiration. Question being (and had been asked), is whether it has merit other than better correctness when not being used as an RSA padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially describing a salted hash which is very important for some post-quantum signature schemes. In some lattice-based schemes it is important that the same signing key never be used with the same hash so that some message-replay defence is required. Schemes such as [FALCON](https://falcon-sign.info) achieve the anti-replay by salting the message before hashing. Your method is one way in which this could be achieved.

Comment: Could you explain how salted hashing differ from plain randomized hashing? Does salted hashing require the salt to be verifiable?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the distinction. I have heard people call secret salt values (ones that can only be verified by some people) pepper, but it's not a term that I use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_(cryptography)